# Self-Hosted Wcf Service with Certificate client authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

I have a self-hosted wcf service which uses wsHttpBinding with Transport security. I want the service to authenticate a client using a certificate.

When the client communicates with the service using clientCredentialsType set to 'None' everything works fine. 
The certificate was created with OpenSSL (self-signed) and registered with netsh on a specific port. The name of the certificate is DomainName (machine name in my case).

**Update**
I have created certificates for both client and server and placed them in each others Trusted Root stores (server certificate in client's store and vice-versa).

I've gone over a lot of articles and other questions at SOF but even the ones that look relevant couldn't help me resolve the issue.

## Current Configuration

### Service

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="Service">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" contract="SomeNamespace.IService"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://domain:port/Something/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>    
  </system.serviceModel>
```

### Client

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <client>  
      <endpoint address="https://domain:port/Something/"   
                behaviorConfiguration="endpointCredentialBehavior"  
                binding="wsHttpBinding"   
                bindingConfiguration="Binding"   
                contract="SomeNamespace.IService"/>  
    </client>  
    <behaviors>  
      <endpointBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="endpointCredentialBehavior">  
          <clientCredentials>  
            <clientCertificate findValue="DomainName"  
                               storeLocation="LocalMachine"  
                               storeName="My"  
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />  
          </clientCredentials>  
        </behavior>  
      </endpointBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
    <bindings>  
      <wsHttpBinding>         
        <binding name="Binding">  
          <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>  
          </security>  
        </binding>  
      </wsHttpBinding>  
    </bindings>  
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I get the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing we need to do. We should make their certificate trusted by each other. the server’s certificate must be trusted by the client and the client’s certificate must be trusted by the server.
Specifically, the server certificate is installed in the client Trusted Root Certification Authorities, the client certificate is installed in the server Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. It is best to use a local machine certificate store. We could check the certificate by using Certlm.msc command.
[image]
Please refer to the official document with regards to this issue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
For some special certificates created by other special tools, such as PowerShell, we had better make the target framework of the project (server and client) above 4.6.2.
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/12000
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I've already done what you suggested and it still didn't work (I've updated the question with this information). I also went over the article you referred me to and still to no avail.
Is there anything else you can suggest doing?

Comment: Before I made the application works properly, I also got this exception. Have you added the Everyone account to the management group of the certificate private key? Besides, why don't you have Identity section in your client configuration file? If you invoke the service by adding a service reference, the configuration file automatically adds identity section, as follows. 
                <identity>
<dns value="vabqia593VM"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>

Comment: the value is the public key of the server certificate or machine name of the server.

Comment: Can you point me where I add the Everyone account to the management group?

Comment: Our project has a common client infrastructure because we have multiple different clients that connect to the same server and we send our requests manually using ClientBase class. I will check how to add the Identity section manually.

Comment: It is in the certificate store,right click the certificate and manage private key. You could call the service in a separate project,then check the identity section.

Comment: I'll try all your suggestions and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your configuration file looks okay.
i have same issue with my 3rd party client certificate(public key) no matter where i add that certificate is still doesn't works.
However i've managed to make it work with my self-signed client certificate. i just had to add client CA certificate to Trusted Root Certification authorities on server.

i found those two topics helpful in determining some of issues: 
[Mutual authentication with a IIS hosted WCF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bradleycotier/2011/12/14/mutual-authentication-with-a-iis-hosted-wcf-data-service-installed-in-a-workgroup-environment/)
[WCF – 2 Way SSL Security using Certificates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/imayak/2008/09/12/wcf-2-way-ssl-security-using-certificates/)

Hope it will be helpfull for you. i'll post updates if i'll manage to solve this problem.

Comment: i've solved the issue with 3rd party client certificate(public key), the problem was that due testing i did't had private key of that certificate so my server couldn't validate client. also i've managed to properly enable certificate mapping in IIS (used Netsh commands to enabled DS mapping) and restric acces to all users whom certifcate isn't used for mapping.
 i have added authorization in webconfig instead of disabling anonymous access in IIS:  
  <system.web>
  <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>